# Wordpress Frontend Post Form - image not uploading

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin to allow users to post from the frontend by filling a form and uploading an image. The problem is the image is not uploading but I can see its name in my library.

**HTML FORM**

```
<form id="fep-new-post" name="new_post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
    <p><label>Nom de l'ouvrage*</label><input type="text" id ="nom" name="nom" /></p>
    <p><label>Auteur*</label><input type="text" id ="auteur" name="auteur" /></p>
    <p><label>Nombre de pages *</label><input type="text" id ="nombre_de_pages" name="nombre_de_pages" /></p>
    <p><label>Catégorie *</label><input type="text" id ="categorie" name="categorie" /></p>
    <p><label>Résumé*</label><textarea class="fep-content" name="resume" id="resume" tabindex="1" rows="4" cols="60"></textarea></p>
    <input type='file' id="file" name='image' data-allowed-file-extensions='["png", "jpg", "gif", "jpeg"]' accept='image/*'>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" tabindex="3"  />                   
</form>
```

**Processing PHP**

```
function fep_add_post(){

    $meta=[];
    $meta['nom']= $_Post['nom'];
    $meta['auteur']= $_Post['auteur'];
    $meta['nombre_de_pages']= $_Post['nombre_de_pages'];
    $meta['categorie']= $_Post['categorie'];
    $meta['resume']= $_Post['resume'];


$post_id =  array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($nom),
    'post_type'     => 'livre',
    'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
    'meta_input'    => $meta,
    'post_status'   => 'pending'
    );
$new_post = wp_insert_post($post_id);   

$filename = $_POST['file'];


$parent_post_id = $new_post;


$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );


$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();


$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
'post_content'   => '',
'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);


$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );


require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );


$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $parent_post_id, $attach_id );

if ($new_post == 0 ){
    echo json_encode( array('loggedin' => false, 'message' => __('Echec dinsertion')));
}   else{
    echo json_encode( array('loggedin' => true, 'message' => __('Insertion effectuer')));
}
 die();     
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {

$( '#fep-new-post' ).on( 'submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(this);
    var files = $('#file').val();

    console.log(files);

    data.append('file',files);
    data.append('action', 'fep_add_post');
    $.ajax({
        url: post_livre_submit,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(new_post!= 0){
                $( 'form#fep-new-post #result' ).html("<h2>"+data.message+"</ph2>");
            }else{
                alert('file not uploaded');
            }
        },
    });
});
});
```

Also I did check my uploads folder and the image is not there and the path name in my library is C:\fakepath\image2.png

Comment: Shouldn't `$_POST['file']` be `$_FILES['file']` instead?

Comment: Doing that doesn't get the file name

Comment: My bad. It should be `$_FILES['image']` instead since your input field's name is `image`.

Comment: I finally solved the problem by using `$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', $_POST['file'] );` to do the upload

Answer (score 0):

```
media_handle_upload()
```

> Save a file submitted from a POST request and create an attachment
>   post for it.

I will add the following example you have to reform as per your need :

```
 if ( isset( $_POST['html-upload'] ) && ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
        $id = media_handle_upload( 'async-upload', $post_id ); //post id of Client Files page
        unset( $_FILES );
        if( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
            $errors['upload_error'] = $id;
            $id = false;
        }

        if( $errors ) {
            echo "<p>There was an error uploading your file.</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>Your file has been uploaded.</p>";
        }
    }
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/